# How to use autocomplete searching two tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

I have two tables, 'states' and 'cities' and I would like the auto-complete to search any result in the two tables from the fields state and city. I haven't been able to do it yet but I have been able to search one table but cant seem to figure out how to search both.

Tables:

```
States
======
id
state

Cities
======
id
city
```

This is how I am looping through the result...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $row_array['id'] = $row['stateid'];
    $row_array['value'] = $row['state'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect to MySQL, instead of using a query on a single table, use this

```
select 'state' as type, id, state
from states
union all
select 'city', id, city
from cities
```

The resultant column named "State" contains states as well as city names.  You will probably want to use the "type" column as well to identify whether the chosen name (from the array) is a state or city.

It may be easier to do a wrapper around it, so that you can filter on the combined result:

```
SELECT type, id, state
FROM
(
    select 'state' as type, id, state
    from states
    union all
    select 'city', id, city
    from cities
) X
WHERE ...  # you can put a where clause here
```

Comment: So inside the while loop, what would I send to the Jquery script? The autocomplete as I know it has built in fields it needs before it will even work such as the 'id' and the 'value' fields, so would I have to add anything inside the while loop?

Comment: @Cory Changing the query as shown merely splices the city data together with the state data (returned to PHP). Display wise, it will work, but as to where the data ends up, only you will know.

Comment: Ah I see. Would I be able to use a "where state like '%" . $_GET['term'] . "%'" in that statement like normal?

Comment: Oh the user side, I answered this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141887/jquery-autocomplete-with-json-beginners-question/3142989#3142989) on how autocomplete can work with combined data... I hope it helps :)